# In struts 2 how to call method of same action with passing parameter along with method call

Tags: java, struts2

I wanted to make a call to a method of same action and pass parameter to it.
Can anybody tell me how can i make a call to it.

Usually in action class if same class method is called in another method of same class then just we write :

return methodName();

but in case i want to make a call with passing parameter along with the call;

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways I can think of to do this.

If you want to call the method on the same action:

```
<s:property value="methodName(parameter)"/>
```

If the method is in another action and you have specified the method in that action in your action mappings:

```
<s:action name="actionName_mehtodName" executeResult="false">
    <s:param name="paramName" value="paramValue"/>
<s:action/>
```

In latter case you if you set `executeResult` to `false` you can use the action to set properties on `ValueStack` for later use. But if set to `true` whatever the result of that action is, it will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Can you save it to a class variable of your action class so that all methods can access it?

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {

   private Object parameter; //The parameter to be passed between methods

   public String firstAction() {
       ...
       parameter = something; //Set the parameter for second action to access
       return secondAction();
   }
   ...
}
```